# "Forbidden" in Custom Login Module in Wildfly

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8, jaas

I have configured custom login module

Added an Application user "jmsuser" in group "guest" for realm ApplicationRealm. But still I am getting "Forbidden" in the resultant page.

Standalone-full.xml

```
<default-security-domain value="MyLoginModule"/>
<security-domain name="MyLoginModule" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="com.auth.MyLoginModule" flag="required"/>
                    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

Web.xml

```
<security-role>  
    <role-name>guest</role-name>  
</security-role>  
<security-constraint>  
    <web-resource-collection>  
        <web-resource-name></web-resource-name>  
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
        <http-method>GET</http-method> 
    <http-method>POST</http-method> 
    </web-resource-collection>  
    <auth-constraint>  
        <role-name>guest</role-name>  
    </auth-constraint>  
</security-constraint>  
<login-config>  
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>  
<realm-name>MyLoginModule</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web> 
    <security-domain>MyLoginModule</security-domain> 
</jboss-web>
```

MyLoginModule.java

```
public boolean login() throws LoginException
    {
//returns true;
}
```

Audit.log

```
11:17:51,560 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX000224: End getAppConfigurationEntry(MyLoginModule), AuthInfo: AppConfigurationEntry[]:
[0]
LoginModule Class: com.auth.MyLoginModule
ControlFlag: LoginModuleControlFlag: required
Options:

11:19:16,232 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX000210: defaultLogin, login context: javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext@8ba05ec, subject: Subject(1075984995).principals=com.auth.MyLoginModulePrincipal@1936852516(MyLoginModulePrincipal:  jmsuser)
11:19:18,863 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX000207: updateCache, input subject: Subject(1075984995).principals=com.auth.MyLoginModulePrincipal@1936852516(MyLoginModulePrincipal:  jmsuser), cached subject: Subject(689516194).principals=com.auth.MyLoginModulePrincipal@1936852516(MyLoginModulePrincipal:  jmsuser)
11:19:18,865 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX000208: Inserted cache info: org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager$DomainInfo@6a06d399
11:19:18,866 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX000201: End isValid, result = true
11:19:18,879 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX000354: Setting security roles ThreadLocal: null
```

Update: 
I have added principal and roles in subject but still getting Forbidden.PFB updated MyLoginModule class

```
 private Principal userPrincipal;
 private RolePrincipal rolePrincipal;
 private List<String> userGroups;
...
public login(){
//returns true;
}

@Override
    public boolean commit() throws LoginException {

        if (!isAuthenticated) {
            return false;
        } else {

            userPrincipal = new Principal(username);
            subject.getPrincipals().add(userPrincipal);

            if (userGroups != null && userGroups.size() > 0) {
                for (String groupName : userGroups) {
                    rolePrincipal = new RolePrincipal(groupName);
                    subject.getPrincipals().add(rolePrincipal);
                }
            }

            commitSucceeded = true;

            return true;
        }
    }
      private List<String> getRoles() {

        List<String> roleList = new ArrayList<>();
        roleList.add("guest");

        return roleList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use the `ApplicationRealm` and the user/roles defined in its property files then just **remove `jboss-web.xml`** from your deployment. It will use automatically the `other` security domain (the default one) - which uses the `ApplicationRealm` as the user repository.

---

You don't need to touch the `ApplicationRealm` if you want to use your own login module in a new security domain.

What you need to do in your custom login module is:

1. authenticate the user (add a principal with username to the Subject)
2. add some roles to the **`Roles`** group in the Subject

If you use username/password authentication, then the simplest way is to extend abstract PicketBox class `org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule`

Look into the **[JBoss EAP Security Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.4/html-single/Security_Guide/index.html#sect-Custom_Modules)** to get details how to implement custom login modules for JBoss application servers.

Comment: I have added principal and roles in subject but still getting Forbidden.Please check my updated question.

Comment: If you don't want to extend one of the JBoss (PicketBox) login-module classes, then at least look at the `AbstractServerLoginModule` class to understand how to add roles correctly into the Subject - https://github.com/picketbox/picketbox/blob/master/security-jboss-sx/jbosssx/src/main/java/org/jboss/security/auth/spi/AbstractServerLoginModule.java

Answer (score 1):

Does your module extend `AbstractServerLoginModule` either directly or indirectly?

- if yes you need to set `loginOk = true`
- if no `commit` needs to return true as well

Comment: Commit returns true. And the class is implementing LoginModule